# Java - Integrity of txt documents

Tags: java

Within a Java program i've got a bunch of text files which the program reads and writes to (i know this is a really bad way to implement an app) but I need some way to ensure the integrity of the text files every time the program loads.

If the text file is deleted the program will be able to re-create it as it was last. Is there any way of doing something like this where I can store data between program executions? - But the important thing is that i'm able to change the data stored.

(Usually would use a database but it's not an option atm).

edit: (Clarify what I'm looking for)

1. There exists a text file full of data.
2. User deletes the text file.
3. Program detects wrong or missing file and re-creates it from a backup which the user can't get his hands on.

This is the kind of process i'm trying to implement.

Comment: If I were you, I would choose `Object Serialization` over plain files for this situation.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. If the state is stored in the files, how do you recreate them? Surely that information is lost. While the program is running it should be very easy to recreate deleted files. Once the program is shut down, all bets are off. You can throw a massive error but where would the data come from to recreate the file.

Comment: @ pars porahmad I've just checked it out, looks promising, thanks!

Comment: @BoristheSpider - In the text file will be a bunch of usernames, if someone manually deletes the text file I need the program to be able to recreate it as it was. But the list of username will be forever changing. - My question is just is there anyway to store data between executions?

Comment: Again, while the program is running this is easy. But if the program is not running and someone deletes the file where will the information come from to recreate the file?

Comment: @BoristheSpider - Thats the million dollar question! - I'm looking for the best way to store data locally in a safe way

Comment: You can't. As I said, you can check that all the files exist and throw an error if they do not. But you cannot recreate deleted data. You should use [JPA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Persistence_API) and an embedded database, such as [HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/), for better control but you simply **cannot prevent** the user for breaking things if they want. Unless of course you store the data externally - send it down the wire or some such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't save data locally in a safe way. Everything that is stored on the users machine is under the users control. You can make them jump through hoops, like with using encryption or storing files in obscure formats in strange places, but you will just make it less convenient to change the files, not impossible for a determined user.

The only way to get around this is to store the data online.

Comment: Where do you think would be the best place to store a file on the users machine? - I'm thinking some kind of hidden directory, I'd need to be storing it on mac and window.

Comment: @Crizly There is none! Your whole strategy is flawed.

Comment: @Crizly I find all this highly questionable. As a user I want to know where all the files are and what they do. I will not install a program that does strange stuff. I am a UNIX user though...

Comment: There really is no other way to do this apart from a database is there? - I give up lol, database it is. (Thank you all for the info).

Comment: @Crizly A local database isn't immune to user manipulation either. Databases are nothing but well-organized files stored on the hard drive.